# Removing elements from the root web page with document.URL.includes( )

Tags: javascript

My question today involves changing elements on a web page according to the URL of the page that is loaded at the moment. My concept is a full screen div that has a low opacity, allowing the background to come through, but I need to remove the other elements that are on the page because they shouldn't be visible through the full screen div.

My JS is below. Currently it works, except for on the initial page load (because the root URL doesn't contain 'index.html' to begin with). I have considered just changing the background of the full-screen div and adding a linear gradient to it as well. As I'm writing this, that actually seems to be the best option and I probably shouldn't be removing each element with JS.

Although, I would still like to get your advice about this as I may have a use case for such a technique in the future.
'''

```
// NAV MENU

const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu__btn');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu');
const discover = document.querySelector('#discover');
const titles = document.querySelector('.titles');
const hero = document.querySelector('#hero');
let menuOpen = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!menuOpen) {
        if (document.URL.includes('index.html')) {
            discover.style.display = 'none';
            titles.style.display = 'none';
            hero.style.display = 'none';
        }
        menuBtn.classList.add('open');
        navMenu.style.display = 'flex';
        navMenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
        menuOpen = true;
    } else {
        if (document.URL.includes('index.html')) {
            discover.style.display = 'inline-block';
            titles.style.display = 'inline-block';
            hero.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
        menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
        navMenu.style.display = 'none';
        navMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        menuOpen = false;
    }
});
```

'''

Comment: Remove C tag, please.

Comment: Oops I got it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hash to your url (ex: Index.html#hash1), every time you want changes to occur in your page, and in the global scope listen to hashchange event, then in the callback, hide btns, show etc according to the hash you set. But what you are doing can be easily solved with any of the modern js frontend frameworks router.

Add a hash:

```
location.hash = 'hash1'
```

Listen to event:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', ()=>{
  if(location.hash === 'hash1')
  {
//Show something or hide maybe
  }
})
```

Comment: Sounds promising let me try it tonight and get back

Comment: Thanks Roberto. So I went back and looked and my solution actually works (I think my site was cached not loading properly)! I appreciate your insight. I will definitely be revisiting this thread in the future.